# Clickout in jquery

Tags: jquery, click, out

What is the easiest way to do a clickout in jquery Where a div box hides if clicked anywhere outside it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't like the solutions that use `stopPropagation` because often I am using event bubbling to manage various links. I don't want to have to worry that they might stop working if the box exists. My choice would look something like this:

```
var $box = $('#box');
$(document.body).click(function(){
    if (!$box.has(this).length) { // if the click was not within $box
        $box.hide();
    }
});
```

The [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) function filters the selection and returns elements only if they contain the element passed as the parameter (you can also use a selector string, but that isn't relevant here). If the click was outside the box, `length` will be `0` so the conditional will pass and the box will be hidden.

This should be optimised by setting a boolean value for whether the box is currently visible and only doing the `has` call if it is currently visible.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but after looking at Caspar's answer I got it to work by changing `this` to `e.target` and adding `e` as an argument to the callback.

Answer (score 5):

**like this:**

```
$("#thediv").show(0, function() {
   var that = $(this);
   $(document).bind("click", function(e) {
       if($(e.target).attr("id") != that.attr("id")) {
          that.hide();
          $(this).unbind("click");
       }
    });
});
```

fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/XYbmE/3/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('#box').fadeOut();
});

$('#box').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This works because #box will receive the click event first if you clicked inside. Since propagation is stopped, the handler attached to body won't receive it so the box won't be closed unless you clicked outside of the box.

If you want it to hide immediately, use `.hide()`

I've got the stopPropagation() trick from [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: This would hide it if you click inside the div, not outside.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use this lib https://github.com/gsantiago/jquery-clickout. It's awesome!

```
$('button').on('clickout', function (e) {
  console.log('click outside button')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that jQuery has the ["focusout"](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event for form elements, not sure if it could maybe be used for a

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click function to the document itself:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    alert('doc');
});
```

Then bind a function to the same event on the div itself and return false so the event will not bubble up to the document.

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e){
    alert('mydiv click');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Better use `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `return false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my solution

```
    var ClickOut = {};

    ClickOut.list = [];

    ClickOut.Add = function(jqel, callback) {
        var i = ClickOut.list.push({jqel:jqel, callback:callback});
        return (i-1);
    }

    ClickOut.Remove = function(i) {
        ClickOut.list.splice(i, 1);
    }

    ClickOut.Init = function() {
        $('body').click(function(e) {
            for(var x = 0; x < ClickOut.list.length; x++) {
                if (!ClickOut.list[x].jqel.has(e.target).length) {
                    ClickOut.list[x].callback();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```